How can I pack four 8 bit ints into a float and pass them to a shader?
Ive got to pack four 8 bit ints into a float in c++ and pass them to GLSL 130  (dont ask why, but there is absolutely no way around it).
I found this code online
float packIEEE754binary32( int byte3,  int byte2,  int byte1,  int byte0) {



    const int emax = 127;

    // Extract sign bit
    int sign = (byte3 & 0x80) ? -1 : 1;

    // Extract exponent
    int exponent = (byte3 & 0x7F) * 2;
    exponent += (byte2 & 0x80) ? 1 : 0;
    exponent -= emax;

    // Extract mantissa
    int mantissa = (byte2 & 0x7F) << 16;
    mantissa += byte1 << 8;
    mantissa += byte0;
    mantissa += 0x800000; // Add the implicit leading 1

    // Handle special cases
    if (exponent == 128) {
        return sign * (mantissa ? std::nanf("") : INFINITY);
    }
    if (exponent == -127) {
        return sign * ldexpf(mantissa, -149);
    }

    // Normalize and calculate the float value
    float result = ldexpf(mantissa, exponent - 23);
    return sign * result;
}

in GLSL
const int emax=127;
// Input: x>=0
// Output: base 2 exponent of x if (x!=0 && !isnan(x) && !isinf(x))
//         -emax if x==0
//         emax+1 otherwise
int floorLog2(float x)
{
    if(x==0.) return -emax;
    // NOTE: there exist values of x, for which floor(log2(x)) will give wrong
    // (off by one) result as compared to the one calculated with infinite precision.
    // Thus we do it in a brute-force way.
    for(int e=emax;e>=1-emax;--e)
        if(x >= exp2(float(e))) return e;
    // If we are here, x must be infinity or NaN
    return emax+1;
}

// Input: any x
// Output: IEEE 754 biased exponent with bias=emax
int biasedExp(float x) { 
    return emax + floorLog2(abs(x)); 
}

// Input: any x such that (!isnan(x) && !isinf(x))
// Output: significand AKA mantissa of x if !isnan(x) && !isinf(x)
//         undefined otherwise
float significand(float x)
{
    // converting int to float so that exp2(genType) gets correctly-typed value
    float expo = float(floorLog2(abs(x)));
    return abs(x) / exp2(expo);
}

// Input: x\in[0,1)
//        N>=0
// Output: Nth byte as counted from the highest byte in the fraction
int part(float x,int N)
{
    // All comments about exactness here assume that underflow and overflow don't occur
    const float byteShift = 256.;
    // Multiplication is exact since it's just an increase of exponent by 8
    for(int n = 0; n < N; ++n)
        x *= byteShift;

    // Cut higher bits away.
    // $q \in [0,1) \cap \mathbb Q'.$
    float q = fract(x);

    // Shift and cut lower bits away. Cutting lower bits prevents potentially unexpected
    // results of rounding by the GPU later in the pipeline when transforming to TrueColor
    // the resulting subpixel value.
    // $c \in [0,255] \cap \mathbb Z.$
    // Multiplication is exact since it's just and increase of exponent by 8
    float c = floor(byteShift * q);
    return int(c);
}

// Input: any x acceptable to significand()
// Output: significand of x split to (8,8,8)-bit data vector
ivec3 significandAsIVec3(float x)
{
    ivec3 result;
    float sig = significand(x)/2.; // shift all bits to fractional part
    result.x=part(sig,0);
    result.y=part(sig,1);
    result.z=part(sig,2);
    return result;
}

// Input: any x such that !isnan(x)
// Output: IEEE 754 defined binary32 number, packed as ivec4(byte3,byte2,byte1,byte0)
ivec4 unpackIEEE754binary32(float x)
{
    int e = biasedExp(x);
    // sign to bit 7
    int s = x < 0. ? 128 : 0;
    ivec4 binary32;
    binary32.yzw = significandAsIVec3(x);
    // clear the implicit integer bit of significand
    if (binary32.y >= 128) {
        binary32.y-=128;
    }
    
    // put lowest bit of exponent into its position, replacing just cleared integer bit
    binary32.y += 128 * int(mod(float(e),2.));
    // prepare high bits of exponent for fitting into their positions
    e /= 2;
    // pack highest byte
    binary32.x = e + s;


    return binary32;
}

This code sort of works if I limit myself to four 7 bit ints.
The problem with the above code is that they are using the sign and the exponent to unpack the first byte, but the exponent is already a byte, they should be adding the sign to the mantissa...
Does anyone have any code that actually works?
I could try to upgrade to GLSL 150 or 160 but probably no higher. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

The packIEEE754binary32 you show cannot work for the exponent == 128 case because there are only four different values it can return (+1 or −1 for sign multiplied by either std::nanf("") or INFINITY), but there are 2^24 values it needs to encode (32 bits minus the 8 that cause exponent == 128 to be true). In the absence of a C implementation that supports working with NaN payloads, the only way to encode 32 bits, with no constraints on their values, into an IEEE-754 binary32 is to copy them into the float at the byte level, as with memcpy.

Similarly, the bits cannot be retrieved from a float without support for handling NaN payloads. I am not familiar with GLSL, but GLSL ES 3 and GLSL 4 have floatBitsToUInt, which appears to be exactly what one needs to get the bytes out of a float.

packIEEE754binary32 could be float packIEEE754binary32(int byte3, int byte2, int byte1, int byte0) { float f; memcpy(&f, (signed char []) { byte3, byte2, byte1, byte0 }, sizeof f); return f; } if the endianness works for you.

Thanks. It does appear that the problem is unsolvable given GLSL 130s lack of support for bit manipulation and lack of floatBitsToUInt(). I guess Ill just leave the question up though
